# How can I enable Trash feature in a NTFS partition with permissions?

Tags: permissions, fstab, ntfs, trash

I'm currently trying to able the Trash feature in a NTFS partition mounted automatically on boot. To do that I'm using the permissions option in my fstab:

```
UUID=1CACB8ABACB88136 /media/FILES ntfs defaults,permissions,relatime 0 0
```

then I changed the permissions:

```
sudo chown :users -R /media/FILES/
sudo chmod g+rwx -R /media/FILES/
```

It works great except I continue to not have the trash feature. I can read, write, execute being member of  the users group but I cannot use the Trash feature in Nautilus, only permanent delete.  Any thoughts ?

BR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey guys I've found the solution, removing my old .Trash folder that was there but wasn't working:

```
sudo rm -rf /media/FILES/.Trash-1000
```

worked like a charm, I'm now able to move to Trash from nautilus. And I'm pretty sure that If I create a new user he will be able to have its own trash too.

Comment: I don't have this dir and thw Linux's Trash for an NTFS partition doesn't work since ages... Do you have any clue on this? Thanks.

Comment: I had this folder, and deleted it, but no change

Answer (score 1):

There needs to be a folder called the .Trash-{userid} in the root of the mounted partition, to enable the Trash functionality inside nautilus.

Permissions of g+w is only needed to create the folder. I wouldn't suggest giving all users from that group write access unless otherwise needed.