# How to enable Trash on NTFS

Tags: ubuntu, ntfs, trash

In Ubuntu 18.10 I can't use the trash on my NTFS partition. When deleting a file Nautilus prompts to permanently remove it.
In Solus trash works on this partition.

Any ideas how to enable trash or what other info could I provide?

#### My setup:

- fstab entry: `/dev/disk/by-uuid/530B3F8539F30AB8 /mnt/Daten auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,x-gvfs-name=Daten,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0`
- `gvfs` is installed
- `ll` shows `drwxrwxrwx` rights on `/mnt/Daten/`

#### What I tried:

- adding `uid=1000` and `gid=1000` options to `/etc/fstab`
- removing/renaming old trash folder ([How can I enable Trash feature in a NTFS partition with permissions?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/366388/how-can-i-enable-trash-feature-in-a-ntfs-partition-with-permissions))

Comment: please check whether currently logged in user id is 1000 or not. you can check it with `id` command. uid must be fine, you wont need gid parameter.

Comment: yes, `id` prints `uid=1000`; ok thx

Answer (score 0):

I know this is 1 year+ old but;
If someone in the future would need this:

#### To enable "delete-permanently button":

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences show-delete-permanently true
```

#### To disable "delete-permanently button":

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences show-delete-permanently false
```

//Best Wishes!